# Manually implementing default font does not update getData()

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am trying to manually implement default fonts, since there is no straightforward way to do so. I cannot edit the p tag CSS to be a certain font as I want to keep previous text the same, only new text should be defaulted.

For example, I have code like this:

```
editor.model.document.on('change:data', event => {
          if (element.firstChild.nodeName === 'BR') {
             element.setAttribute('style', 'font-family:Helvetica;font-size:24px');
          }
})
```

In the editor and the DOM, this works. However, when I call editor.getData(), the font family and font size are not there. I believe its because the model or view strips out the attributes. I am not sure how I would make it so the attributes stay in the model/view and updates getData as well.

I have tried upcasting and downcasting, but was not able to get it to work. I'm not sure I am doing it right or if its actually needed. I tried using the writer and classes too, but didnt see the changes in getData() or when I opened the Inspector

```
editor.conversion.for('upcast').attributeToAttribute({
    view: {
            key: 'font-family'
     },
    model: {
      key: 'fontFamily',
      value: true,
    },
});

editor.conversion.for('downcast').attributeToAttribute( {
  model: 'font-family',
  view: {
    key: 'style',
    value: viewWriter => (attributeValue, viewElement) => {
      viewWriter.setStyle('font-family', attributeValue, viewElement);
    },
  },
});
```

How would I go about making getData reflect my changes in the UI/DOM? Please and thank you